Value Error in code for neural network approximation
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the target function f(x) = sin(x)^2
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)**2

# Generate training dataset
np.random.seed(0)  # For reproducibility
num_samples = 100
x_train = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, num_samples)
y_train = f(x_train)

# Initialize coefficients
n = len(x_train)
a = np.random.randn(n)  # Coefficients for linear combination
b = np.random.randn()   # Constant term
m = 10  # Number of neurons
alphas = np.random.randn(m, n)  # Weights for ReLU neurons
ts = np.random.randn(m)         # Thresholds for ReLU neurons
cs = np.random.randn(m)         # Coefficients for ReLU neurons

# Implement Neural Network Approximation
def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)

def f_N(x):
    return np.dot(a, x) + b + np.sum(cs[:, np.newaxis] * relu(np.dot(alphas, x) - ts[:, np.newaxis]), axis=0)

# Define Loss Function
def loss_function(a, b, cs):
    predictions = f_N(x_train)
    return np.mean((predictions - y_train)**2)

# Gradient Descent Optimization
def gradient_descent(learning_rate=0.01, num_iterations=1000):
    losses = []
    for i in range(num_iterations):
        # Compute gradients
        predictions = f_N(x_train)
        error = predictions - y_train
        
        grad_a = np.outer(error, x_train) / num_samples
        grad_b = np.mean(error)
        
        relu_grad = np.dot(cs[:, np.newaxis] * (np.dot(alphas, x_train) - ts[:, np.newaxis] > 0), alphas)
        grad_cs = np.sum(error[:, np.newaxis] * relu_grad, axis=0) / num_samples
        
        # Update coefficients
        a -= learning_rate * grad_a
        b -= learning_rate * grad_b
        cs -= learning_rate * grad_cs

        # Clipping or projecting cs to ensure they stay within bounds
        cs = np.clip(cs, -1, 1)  # Example clipping between -1 and 1

        # Compute current loss
        current_loss = loss_function(a, b, cs)
        losses.append(current_loss)

        # Print loss for monitoring
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print(f"Iteration {i}, Loss: {current_loss}")

    return losses

# Perform gradient descent
losses = gradient_descent()

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# Plot target function
plt.plot(x_train, y_train, label='Target function: $f(x) = \sin(x)^2$', color='blue')

# Plot neural network approximation
y_pred = f_N(x_train)
plt.plot(x_train, y_pred, label='Neural network approximation', linestyle='--', color='red')

plt.title('Neural Network Approximation vs Target Function')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

# Plot loss curve
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.plot(losses, label='Training Loss')
plt.title('Training Loss over Iterations')
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()


The goal of the code is as follows:
Define the target function f(x) = sin(x)^2 and generate a training dataset {(x_i, y_i)} where y_i = f(x_i) for a range of x_i values.
Initialize the neural network coefficients a, b, and c_i with random values and generate samples (alpha_1,t_1),...,(alpha_m,t_m) from a standard gaussian distribution.
Implement the neural network approximation fN(x) = a^Tx+b+sum{i=1}^{m} ci\sigma(alpha{i}^T-t_i) as described in the image, using the initialized coefficients.
Define a loss function L(a, b, c_1, ..., c_m) that measures the difference between the neural network approximation f_N(x_i) and the target function f(x_i) for the training data points (x_i, y_i). For example, you could use the mean squared error: L(a, b, c_1, ..., c_m) = Σ_i (f_N(x_i) - y_i)^2
Use linear regression to minimize the loss function L with respect to the coefficients a, b, and c_i. This can be done using gradient descent or other optimization algorithms.
During the optimization process, ensure that the coefficients stay within the provided bounds by clipping or projecting them back onto the feasible region defined by the bounds.
I get the following error and am unable to debug it:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 68
     65     return losses
     67 # Perform gradient descent
---> 68 losses = gradient_descent()
     70 # Plot the results
     71 plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

Cell In[30], line 41
     38 for i in range(num_iterations):
     39     # Compute gradients
     40     predictions = f_N(x_train)
---> 41     error = predictions - y_train
     43     grad_a = np.outer(error, x_train) / num_samples
     44     grad_b = np.mean(error)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (100,) 

if anybody could help me out that would be greatly appreciated.
